# Is it possible to use directx video acceleration on windows phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8, dxva

I followed the instruction of DXVA on MSDN to try on windows phone 8, but I cannot build my code since there is no Dxva2.lib in the WP8 SDK foloder. Without the lib I can do nothing of DXVA, so I want to know if WP8 support DXVA development or it's only supported by desktop version of D3D?